# RSpec stop method

Tags: ruby, rspec

Quick rspec question here.

Given the following test...

```
it 'sets the correct params' do
  property = 'blahblah'
  expect(ConnectionClass).to receive(:new).with({ opt1: param1, opt2: property })
  subject.send(:do_things, nil, nil).and_return_nil
end
```

and the following method...

```
private
def do_things(param1, param2)
  connection = ConnectionClass.new(opt1: param1, opt2: param2)
  ##
  # How do i stop the test from continue beyond this point? :(
  ##
  some_var = connection.build_request do |blah|
    # ...
  end

  some_var.some_attribute 
end
```

Running the test results in the following failure:

```
Failures:

  1) Klass#do_things sets the correct params
     Failure/Error: subject.send(:do_things, nil, nil).and_return_nil
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `build_request' for nil:NilClass
     # ./lib/blah/Klass.rb:46:in `make_request'
     # ./spec/lib/blah/Klass_spec.rb:79:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

For this test, all i care about is that `ConnectionClass` is initialized correctly -- how can i prevent the call to `build_request` and eventual `some_attribute`?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally a pretty good signal that you either need to refactor your code, or you are testing things that you need to not be testing. Rather than testing the implementation ("This class is instantiated with these parameters") consider testing your outputs (For input X, `do_things` should return output Y and have side effects Z). If you think "I want this test to stop in the middle of this method", you need to refactor the method you're testing so that you can discretely test just the bits you want to test.

That said, if you don't want to change your approach here, you could just return a double from your stub, so that it can complete the method.

```
some_var   = double(some_attribute: "value")
connection = double(build_request: some_var)
expect(ConnectionClass).to receive(:new).with({ opt1: param1, opt2: property }).
  and_return(connection)
```

Comment: Chris thank you for your excellent answer. I think you are correct in thinking my code needs to be refactored.  Maybe this is a time where i should 'listen to my tests'.  unfortunately i'm having a hard time understanding how i could break apart/refactor the code.  Would it be possible for you to show me a sample of how you would break apart and test my sample code into a good refactoring?  I have a really hard time identifying how to do that sort of thing

Comment: I would need to know why you're trying to test that that object is created with those parameters. Why does it matter for implementation purposes? With no other information, I would create a factory method that I can test to ensure that for a given (param1, param2) input, I receive the proper ConnectionClass instance output, but I don't think that's going to get at the heart of what you really want to test for.

Comment: Chris, i think explaining the purpose is beyond the scope of this question so i will leave it as is.  Thanks again for your great answer. I'll mark it as the correct one because it helped me greatly.